# What is the value in CSS for border when using tables?

Tags: html, css, html-table

What is the value in CSS for border when using tables? For example:

This is my desired look.

```
<table border=4px  >
 <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but I want to do it with CSS only. So I tried inline like so

```
<table style="
border-width: 4px;
    border-spacing: 3px;
    border-style: outset;
    border-color: gray;
    border-collapse: separate;
    background-color: white;
    border-width: 2px;
    padding: 1px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: gray;
    background-color: white;
    border-width: 2px;
" >
 <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

When I do this the cell borders are gone (at least in Firefox). I tried using the wizard from here http://www.somacon.com/p141.php but it does not help. No matter what I do I can not get these "inner walls" to appear without using `"table border=1px"`?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Style/Tables/examples.html. You need to apply the border to the cells as well. `table, td, th { border: 4px outset gray; }`

Comment: that is what I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing i would suggest, is have a look [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)

now after you learnt basic css and how to use styles, to apply "inner" borders to a table, you basically apply the borders to the cells themselves:

```
table tr th,
table tr td{
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

or separately:

```
table tr th,
table tr td{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
}
```

and then, to get rid of the cell spacing you apply this to the table itself:

```
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

<kbd>**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/L966wy9o/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can add a separate style tag elsewhere:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    table tr td { 
        border: 4px gray solid;
    } 
    table tr th {
        border: 4px gray solid;
    }
    </style>
```